# Create a new language in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext, textmate, sublimetext3

We have a new language in our lab and we have stuff that provides syntax highlighting, etc in emacs but currently there's nothing for sublime text.

I don't want to create syntax highlighting for this language but I want the following things:

1. The language is similar to Haskell --- so it basically reads Haskell syntax highlighting (however wrong it, is not a concern yet). This can be done by setting an extension for this new language in Haskell.sublime-settings. But ->
2. I need this new language to have tab_size set as 4 whereas for Haskell, it is 2.

I am unsure how to accomplish this in Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your syntax builds upon or extends Haskell, I'd start by importing the Haskell syntax rules

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>fileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>my-extension</string>
    </array>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>My Language</string>
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>include</key>
            <string>source.haskell</string>
        </dict>
        <!-- custom syntax here -->
    </array>
    <key>scopeName</key>
    <string>source.haskell.myExt</string>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You can then start adding your custom syntax or overwriting Haswell defaults, e.g.

```xml
<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>(\b|^\s*)(?i)(list|of|my|keywords)\b</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>keyword.command.myExt</string>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>\b(true|on)\b</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>constant.boolean.true.myExt</string>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>\b(false|off)\b</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>constant.boolean.false.myExt</string>
</dict>

<dict>
    <key>match</key>
    <string>\b((0(x|X)[0-9a-fA-F]+)|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?))\b</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>constants.nummeric.myExt</string>
</dict>
```

I recommend having a look at `Haskell.tmLanguage` prior to creating your custom, take a look at its structure and naming scheme.

I'm not sure whether tab-size is what you would define in the language definition. I can imagine that you can control this in your syntax settings, though these would probably apply to imported Haskell as well.

```js
{
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false
}
```

Also let me point out that you probably get better response when tagging this question `textmate`, as Sublime Text uses TextMate's `.tmLanguage` files as syntax definitions.